# Requesting a restful service with accept header set to application/xml

Tags: rest, jboss, wildfly, rs

Why requesting a restful service with accept header set to application/xml is returning a Json representation?, in this application in this repository [wildfly / quickstart / helloworld-rs](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-rs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Produces({ "application/json" })` indicates it only produces JSON. If you were to change it to `@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })` then it should work.